# Diameter of a convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry

I've been looking at algorithms for finding the diameter of a convex polygon, and while I like the Shamos' algorithm using antipodal points which is general and applicable to various other problems, I thought I would try and find my own solution/proof that's focused only on the diameter. I haven't taken a look at a proof of the Shamos algorithm yet, so this is a bit of an exercise in proving it. I'll be happy if someone takes a look at it and lets me know whether it makes sense and whether it is $O(n)$.

Suppose we have a convex polygon with $n$ vertices $i_0, i_1, ..., i_{n-1}$.
Start with vertex $i_0$ and find the vertex that is furthest away from it, calling it $i_j$.
Now consider the vertex $i_1$. Observation: if there is a vertex further away from $i_1$ than $i_j$, then its index cannot lie in $(0,j)$. If we show the observation is true, we'll be able to traverse the polygon vertices - for each point we will find the distance between it and the vertex that is furthest from it. As we iterate across the vertices, we always start with the last index that was deduced to be furthest away from the previous iteration vertex. Taking the max of these distances is the diameter.

The fact that the observation is true can be shown using the following diagram:[image: example]

Any vertex with index in $(1, j)$ lies in the circle arc formed by $i_0, i_1, i_j$ (orange in the image). We need to show that this arc is contained inside the larger circle - if that is the case, all vertices with index in $(1, j)$ are closer to $i_1$ than $i_j$ is. Showing this formally can be done using basic geometry.

Quick example: we only need to consider vertices lying on the perimeter of the smaller circle. Take any such vertex $x$, take the mid distance between $x$ and $i_j$, and draw a perpendicular line through it (this line passes through $i_0$). Then all the points in the half that contains $x$ are closer to $x$ than $i_j$, and $i_1$ is inside this half.

Comment: Hi Jake. We discourage, the questions of the type: "please check if my answer is correct". Please see [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/questions-about-correctness-of-a-solution).

Comment: Though, I read your solution. Your observation makes sense. But I do not understand, how it gives $O(n)$ time algorithm. The second pointer could go around the hull many times. When do you stop incrementing the second pointer?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami You are correct, thank you, I implicitly assumed that it makes sense to only update the second pointer until it starts decreasing, but that doesn't work, so you would have to keep checking all the vertices repeatedly.

However I think it could be shown that the sequence of the "furthest away" vertices will not rotate around the hull multiple times.

Comment: Your observation is correct when we are considering $i_1$. Instead of it, consider $i_{j-1}$. Note that $i_{j-1}$ might lie in the half containing $i_j$. In that case, $x$ is farther away from $i_{j-1}$ than $i_j$.